# How to use Firebase Clould Messaging with Liferay Push Notification

Tags: liferay, firebase-cloud-messaging

Liferay Push Notification use Google Cloud Messaging, but recently Google replaced GCM with firebase cloud messaging. Could you please tell me if your push plugin supports FCM or if there is any solution on how to make it work with FCM?

Answer (score 1):

GCM still works, the service hasnt been stop.
Although Liferay doesnt support FCM, i dont doubt it will.
https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/

Answer (score 0):

For Liferay 6.2 EE, Liferay Push plugin supports FCM (the EE version of the plugin https://web.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/48438926) starting with version 1.3.2. For Liferay 7.0+ (both CE and EE) Liferay Push plugin supports FCM starting from version 2.2.0 (https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-70692).